# SQL Server adding extra special characters in query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I am trying to extract some records in a file using BCP command in SQL Server. However when the file is generated, there are extract spaces in between the result for each column.

To try I just wrote basic SQL Query as simple as this

```
select 'ABC', 40, 'TEST','NOTWORKING'
```

When we copy the output of above query and paste it in Notepad, the output comes as

```
ABC 40  TEST    NOTWORKING
```

Notice the space between each value? The file that system is generating using BCP command also has same space coming in the output file which is incorrect. What I want to see in the output file is

```
ABC40TESTNOTWORKING
```

What must be causing this issue? I am simply amazed to see such weird issue and hoping that it can be fixed by some changes or setting. Please help.

```
Sample BCP command
     EXEC xp_cmdshell  'bcp "select ''ABC'', 40, ''TEST'',''NOTWORKING''" queryout "E:\Testfile.txt"  -c -T -S""'
Output in the File - Testfile.txt
     ABC    40  TEST    NOTWORKING
```

Comment: SQL Server does no such thing. Client tools use tabs when you copy data out of grids. It's the most logical choice after all. You haven't posted anything about `bcp` so it's impossible to help. Most likely you haven't specified the field delimiter, or specified a tab

Comment: This isn't a weird issue at all, it's probably how all *grids* work. You haven't posted anything about an actual bcp issue though

Comment: If I copy and paste data out of Excel, I get the same behaviour. Why would you expect a grid view in SSMS to be any different? They, visually, look the same. How you **copy** data from a display layer (which received data from SQL Server) , like SSMS, and how data is extracted using a tool like BCP is completely different.

Comment: These are tabs in your post.

Comment: As for why *tab* is the logical choice, because any *visual* character would be a bad choice. We're talking about grids after all. There are no commas, semicolons, or vertical bars in the text, so there shouldn't be any in the clipboard. A *tab* helps preserve the visual layout up to a point too

Comment: Finally, the SSMS grid may well have put multiple data formats in the clipboard, eg both a text format with tabs, and HTML or RTF with formatting. During copy/paste, the *source* application decides what to put to the clipboard and the *target* application decides which format in there it can read. Obviously, Notepad can only read text. Another application like Excel could read one of the other formats. What you see in Notepad isn't necessarily what's in the Clipboard and definitely not what's in the database

Comment: @vnkotak update your question and put the command there. `bcp` works. People would have noticed 22 years ago (at least) if it didn't.

Comment: @vnkotak why do you want to export data *without* separators? It's impossible to import that data again unless the fields are fixed width. Which is *also* supported by `bcp` if you use the correct format file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably tabs between the values.  If you want a single value, use `concat()`:

```
select CONCAT('ABC', 40, 'TEST', 'NOTWORKING')
```

Comment: What the OP described could be just how any grid copies data into the clipboard.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon. Didn't knew problem could be resolved with as easy as this solution. However, still wondering why simple query adds that tab/special character in the output.

Comment: @vnkotak there's no problem to begin with. I already explained why no special characters are added to the output. It's the default field separator specified in your command line. The *strange* thing is that you want output without separators. That can't be imported by any other tool, unless each field has a fixed length. Fixed length is possible using bcp too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, we have integration with legacy system where the file format is defined and number of characters for each field is defined.

Answer (score 3):

There's no issue. The command line has no field terminator argument, so the default is used, a tab. That's described in the docs :

> **-t field_term**
>
> Specifies the field terminator. The default is \t (tab character). Use this parameter to override the default field terminator. For more information, see [Specify Field and Row Terminators (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).
>
> If you specify the field terminator in hexadecimal notation in a bcp.exe command, the value will be truncated at 0x00. For example, if you specify 0x410041, 0x41 will be used.
>
> If field_term begins with a hyphen (-) or a forward slash (/), do not include a space between -t and the field_term value.

The link points to an entire article that explains how to use terminators, for each of the bulk operations.

As for the Copy/Paste operation, it has nothing to do with SQL Server. SQL Server has no UI, it's a service. I suspect what was pasted in Notepad was copied from an SSMS grid.

SSMS is a *client* tool just like any other. When you copy data from it into the clipboard, it decides what to put there and what format to use. That format can be plain text, using spaces and tabs for layout, RTF, HTML etc.

Plain text with tabs as field separators is probably the *best* choice for any tool, as it preserves the visual layout up to a point and uses only a single character as a separator. A fixed-length layout using spaces could also be used but that would add characters that may well be part of a field.

**Encodings and codepages**

`-c` exports the data using the user's default codepage. This means that text stored in `varchar` fields using a different codepage (collation) may get mangled. Non-visible Unicode characters will also get mangled and appear as something else, or as `?`.

> **-c**
>
> Performs the operation using a character data type. This option does not prompt for each field; it uses char as the storage type, without prefixes and with \t (tab character) as the field separator and \r\n (newline character) as the row terminator. -c is not compatible with -w.

It's better to use export the file as UTF16 using  `-w`.

> **-w**
>
> Performs the bulk copy operation using Unicode characters. This option does not prompt for each field; it uses nchar as the storage type, no prefixes, \t (tab character) as the field separator, and \n (newline character) as the row terminator. -w is not compatible with -c.

The codepage can be specified using the `-C` parameter. `-C 1251` for example will export the data using Windows' Latin1 codepage. 1253 will export it using the Greek codepage.

> **-C { ACP | OEM | RAW | code_page }**
>
> Specifies the code page of the data in the data file. code_page is relevant only if the data contains char, varchar, or text columns with character values greater than 127 or less than 32.

SQL Server 2016 and later can also export text as UTF8 with `-C 65001`. Earlier versions don't support UTF8.

> Versions prior to version 13 (SQL Server 2016 (13.x)) do not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding). Versions beginning with 13 can import UTF-8 encoding to earlier versions of SQL Server.

All this is described in [bcp's online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#character-mode--c-and-native-mode--n-best-practices).

This subject is so important for any database that it has an entire section in the docs, that describes [data format and considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/data-formats-for-bulk-import-or-bulk-export-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), using [format files to specify different settings per column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/format-files-for-importing-or-exporting-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), and [guidelines to ensure compatibility with other applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-data-formats-for-compatibility-when-using-bcp-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I tried with the solution that you have provided. It does work in the sample file, however when i put it on my actual procedure, it replaced that tab spaces in most of the records, but for odd few 10 records now some new special characters are appearing in the file. Surprised, however the "concat" solution is working fine there, so for now am going with "concat" solution, but wondering if you are aware of why would it do that in your solution "-t"?

Comment: @vnkotak What special characters are you talking about? Are you sure they aren't in the data already? Have you exported Unicode data using a single-byte codepage perhaps?

Comment: @vnkotak if you want to export non-USASCII data use -w instead of -c to export the data as Unicode. Or use -C and the codepage you want.

Comment: Yes mate, those characters are not in the data, as when i put "concat" around, then system is removing them. Also the data is straight ASCII data. Anyways, I have kept "-t" in my procedure as well as added "concat" command.

Comment: @vnkotak I'll repeat it, `bcp` works, for decades now. If you have problems, you'll have to find what's going on. It's not bcp. Wrong codepage? Invisible characters that *are* in the data? You haven't posted any example so one can only guess. There are many Unicode characters that may not be visible like non-braking spaces, diacritics, etc. If you export the text as ASCII, which you did, they'll get mangled and appear as something else

Comment: @vnkotak The only thing that *doesn't* need guessing, is that `bcp` works.